# Check the length of value isnumeric jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Telephone:

```
if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {

alert("error invalid number");

    }
```

I am making a simple form that allows the user to sign up but my problem is how to avoid the user should not click only 1 length of value. let I say the length should less than 7, I'll try to add `&& $("#phone").val().length < 7` in if statement. but it wont work :(

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate: `$("#phone").val() < 1000000`

Comment: it can't.. this is my code if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val()) &&$("#phone").val().length < 7 ) {
  
  errorMessage = errorMessage + "* Please Enter Valid Phone Number <br />";
 
  
 }

Comment: Use a regex then. `^\d{7}$` should so it. Then you can do away with the isNumeric. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

You are using an && when you need to use an ||. If it is not numeric or it its length is less than 7.

```
if (! $.isNumeric($("#phone").val()) || $("#phone").val().length < 7) {
    alert("Phone is not numeric");
}
```

You can check at this small jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tsot1pt2/